# Why must __thread follow extern or static

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-local-storage

I'm reading [Kerrisk's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004OEJMZM) and see that the following as a note on 31-4,

> - The `__thread` keyword must immediately follow the `static` or `extern` keyword, if either of these is specified in the variable’s
>     declaration.
> - The declaration of a thread-local variable can include an initializer, in the same manner as a normal global or static variable
>     declaration.
> - The C address (&) operator can be used to obtain the address of a thread-local variable.

I wonder the reason of the fact that the keyword must come behind `static` or `extern`. Can't it be used without any of them?

Its example code,

```
/*************************************************************************\
*                  Copyright (C) Michael Kerrisk, 2018.                   *
*                                                                         *
* This program is free software. You may use, modify, and redistribute it *
* under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the   *
* Free Software Foundation, either version 3 or (at your option) any      *
* later version. This program is distributed without any warranty.  See   *
* the file COPYING.gpl-v3 for details.                                    *
\*************************************************************************/

/* strerror_tls.c

   An implementation of strerror() that is made thread-safe through
   the use of thread-local storage.

   See also strerror_tsd.c.

   Thread-local storage requires: Linux 2.6 or later, NPTL, and
   gcc 3.3 or later.
*/
#define _GNU_SOURCE                 /* Get '_sys_nerr' and '_sys_errlist'
                                       declarations from <stdio.h> */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>                 /* Get declaration of strerror() */
#include <pthread.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"


#define MAX_ERROR_LEN 256           /* Maximum length of string in per-thread
                                       buffer returned by strerror() */
/*   ||||||||||||||||||
//   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
*/
    static     __thread      char buf[MAX_ERROR_LEN];
/* Thread-local return buffer */


char *
strerror(int err)
{
    if (err < 0 || err >= sys_nerr || sys_errlist[err] == NULL) {
        snprintf(buf, MAX_ERROR_LEN, "Unknown error %d", err);
    } else {
        strncpy(buf, sys_errlist[err], MAX_ERROR_LEN - 1);
        buf[MAX_ERROR_LEN - 1] = '\0';          /* Ensure null termination */
    }

    return buf;
}

static void *
threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    char *str;

    printf("Other thread about to call strerror()\n");
    str = strerror(EPERM);
    printf("Other thread: str (%p) = %s\n", str, str);

    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t;
    int s;
    char *str;

    str = strerror(EINVAL);
    printf("Main thread has called strerror()\n");

    s = pthread_create(&t, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_create");

    s = pthread_join(t, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        errExitEN(s, "pthread_join");

    /* If strerror() is not thread-safe, then the output of this printf() be
       the same as that produced by the analogous printf() in threadFunc() */

    printf("Main thread:  str (%p) = %s\n", str, str);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: is `__thread` even a keyword?  I didn't see it in a search of the C standard.  Is that some custom alias for `_Thread_local`?

Comment: The example code has a lot of problems, like using `_sys_errlist` which is deprecated, unsafe, and introduces an ABI dependency on *the particular version of* glibc the program was linked against, due to mess with copy relocations.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  That may be fixable via the contents of the header file:  `lpi_hdr.h`  However, the contents of that file are missing from your question.

Comment: `_Thread_local` is the C11 / C18 standard notation for thread local variables.  The `__thread` notation is firmly in the 'reserved for the system' name space; it could do anything, but presumably functions somewhat like `_Thread_local`, defining that the variable is a thread-local variable.  It's not much different from `__declspec(thread)` — neither better nor worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard C storage class specifier for thread local variables is [`_Thread_local`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1).  The standard also says in [§6.11 Future directions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11):

> 6.11.5 Storage class specifiers
>
> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

Thus, the standard says that storage class keywords (`static`, `extern`, `auto` — don't use it! — `register` — ditto — `_Thread_local` and `typedef`) *should* appear at the start of a declaration.  Where either `static` or `extern` appears and `_Thread_local`, the recommendation from the book is that `static` or `extern` should be first and `_Thread_local` second.

Of course, the book is using `__thread` and not `_Thread_local`.  That's a compiler (implementation) specific keyword that behaves similarly to the standard C `_Thread_local` and Microsoft's `__declspec(thread)`.

The GCC documentation on [thread local storage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Thread-Local.html#Thread-Local) documents (emphasis added):

> At the user level, the extension is visible with a new storage class keyword: `__thread`.  For example:
>
> ```
> __thread int i;
> extern __thread struct state s;
> static __thread char *p;
> ```
>
> The `__thread` specifier may be used alone, with the `extern` or `static` specifiers, but with no other storage class specifier. When used with `extern` or `static`, **`__thread` must appear immediately after the other storage class specifier.**
>
> The `__thread` specifier may be applied to any global, file-scoped static, function-scoped static, or static data member of a class. It may not be applied to block-scoped automatic or non-static data member.

So, what you're seeing is the GCC-specific notation for thread-local storage, and as I noted and as the GCC manual notes, storage class information should come first in a declaration (and GCC explicitly says `__thread` after `static` or `extern`).

See also [Common variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Reread the text you quoted (emphasis mine):

> - The __thread keyword must immediately follow the static or extern keyword, **if either of these is specified** in the variable’s declaration.

So if neither is specified, this clause does not apply.

As for "why", if the claim is true (I suspect it's roughly true but imprecisely stated), it's just a matter of the grammar for "GNU C", where `__thread` comes from. You can look up the grammar requirements for the equivalent `_Thread_local` in the C11 standard.